# How to extend this Regex to accept more variation?

Tags: python, regex

I have this regex which works for what I want it to do.

```
([01]?[0-9]+:?[0-9]*(?:[AP]M)?)-?([01]?[0-9]+:?[0-9]*(?:[AP]M)?)
```

It captures perfectly fine.

```
NO PARKING (SANITATION BROOM SYMBOL) 7AM-7:30AM EXCEPT SUNDAY
```

But then I found another case in my data

```
NO PARKING (SANITATION BROOM SYMBOL) 11:30AM TO 1PM THURS
```

which uses `TO` to separate the from_time and to_time. How can I extend that regex to accept this case? I tried

```
([01]?[0-9]+:?[0-9]*(?:[AP]M)?)\s?-|TO\s??([01]?[0-9]+:?[0-9]*(?:[AP]M)?)
```

With no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your expression, the two alternatives are:

```
([01]?[0-9]+:?[0-9]*(?:[AP]M)?)\s?-
TO\s??([01]?[0-9]+:?[0-9]*(?:[AP]M)?)
```

To make it just the `-` and `TO`, put them in a non-capturing group:

```
([01]?[0-9]+:?[0-9]*(?:[AP]M)?)\s?(?:-|TO)\s?([01]?[0-9]+:?[0-9]*(?:[AP]M)?)
```